# Silverlight set property path in converter?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I have a Listbox, that has multiple datatemplates for it's items. The datatemplate is selected using a converter and interpreting the object collection of the ListBox.

Inside of the converter I am trying to bind a property from the datacontext (outside of the lisbox) to the datatemplate's TextBox control.

ListBox:

```
<telerik:RadListBox
            x:Name="listBox2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="400">

            <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myTestConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource myViewModel}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListBox>
```

The DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestResource1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding propertyLabel}"
                       FontStyle="Italic" Width="120" />
            <TextBox x:Name="valueField"  
                       FontSize="12" Width="50"
                       FontWeight="Bold" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Inside the Converter's convert method:

```
_dt = Application.Current.Resources["TestResource1"] as DataTemplate;
                var context = _dt.LoadContent();

                var ctrl = FindControlByType<TextBox>(context, "valueField");

                Binding binding = new Binding("DataContext.Value1");
                binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(MainPage) };

                TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtBox, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

This doesen't work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason LoadContent isn't working for you is because this is usually called by the control itself during OnApplyTemplate().

In this type of situation, I found it easier to use [XamlReader.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to load a custom piece of DataTemplate and then assigning it to the control.

Comment: Hi, _dt.LoadContent() works fine, my problem is that the binding of "DataContext.Value1" is not picked up. I will try your suggestion of creating the datatemplate dynamically. Maybe that will work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Silverlight calls LoadContent() and the return values are placed in the visual tree. When you call LoadContent, unless you put it in the visual tree, you are not going to see any results.

Comment: I think we are up to something here. I have a relative source in my binding that looks like this: string str = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"" xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:MyListBoxProject""><StackPanel>TextBlock Text=""{Binding propertyLabel}"" /><TextBox Text=""{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainPage}, Path=DataContext.Value1}"" /></StackPanel></DataTemplate>"; but i get this error mesage: Failed to create a 'System.Type' from the text 'local:MainPage .If i bind to a normal property it works fine.

Comment: Regarding your comment on LoadContent, I tried calling LoadContent again after the Binding but without a change in the results. Do you have an example for that one?

Comment: Unfortunately, LoadContent is only useful for the control author. LoadContent creates new controls each time, it never returns the ones that were created by the actual template on screen. To get to those, you'll have to walk the visual tree.

Comment: Thanks Chui for your reply. Maybe an example would be helpful, cause I played around with it and i wasn't able to get anything working. Would it be helpfull if I would put all the files up here?

Comment: You need to qualify the XAML namespace with Assembly: e.g. xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyListBoxProject;Assembly:MyListBoxProject" . I've uploaded sample code here https://github.com/teyc/StackoverflowSilverlightQ

Comment: Thanks Chui ... I'll dig into it today and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Chui fro all your help and time dedicated to this matter.